# Proper way to restart sshd and other daemons

Tags: services, restart, sshd

How should one properly restart `sshd` or otherwise let it know that its configuration file has changed?  Apparently `sudo restart sshd` is no longer the proper way to do this, as attempting to do so gives

```
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the version of Ubuntu your are using to perform this action ?

Comment: You may be on a Ubuntu that is `systemd` based ( 16.04 and newer ). In that case you have to use `systemctl restart sshd`. To check the config you can use `sudo sshd -t`.

Answer (score 4):

The command should be:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

or:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is as follows:

```
systemctl reload sshd.service
```

Restart will cause the entire process to be restarted.